# Is connection string name LocalSqlServer mandatory?

Tags: asp.net

How do i configure connection string for Asp.Net Membership Provider? Do i have to write it by hand or any tool is available in Visual Studio where i can specify connection string as well as algorithm used to store password?

I read one article and it specifies this connection string :-

```
<configuration>



    <connectionStrings>

        <remove name=”LocalSqlServer”/>

        <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=appservicesdb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

    </connectionStrings>



</configuration>
```

This `LocalSqlServer` name doesn't sound too intuitive. How do i change this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's referenced from either your `<membership>` configuration section

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider" >
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="LocalSQLServer"
         applicationName="MyAppName"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

or from the place you initialise `SqlMembershipProvider` in your code.

As far as I can see there's no default - you (or the code example you've copied) must have named it that.